# Print all the dividers from a number, unsupported operand type for string and range

Tags: python, list, divider

I am trying to exercise my python and do exercices. One exercise is to print all dividers of a number.

I thus tried the following:

```
a = input("give me a number:")
give me a number:34
x = range(0,200)

for elem in x:
    y= a /x
    if y == 0:
        print(y)
```

I had the following error: "*unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'range´*"

What am I doing wrong?

wWhy is python considering that "a" is a string? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) ```input``` returns a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this...

```
a = int(input("give me a number: "))
for elem in range(2,a+1):
  if a%elem == 0:
    print(elem)
```

Comment: Many thanks but why do you write "a+1" and why do you start the range with 2? This is clearly may "better" and "tighter" / "concise" than me trying to create another variable where the division take place...many thanks

Comment: @TomasMichel they've done that to include ```a``` as ```a``` is a divisor of itself though this unnecessarily tests every integer between ```a//2``` and ```a```, and they've skipped ```1``` because ```1``` is a divisor of every integer

Comment: haaaaaaaaaaaa my god I am so stupid...but then...you could have also included "1" and in a sense it would not have "hurt"

Comment: well this isn't my answer, but yeah could've done

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), `input` returns a string, therefore you have to convert it to an integer. Secondly, you're dividing by `x` which is a `range` object, you should instead divide by `elem`. You should also start your range object from `1` instead of `0` to avoid dividing by `0`. There is also no need to go up to `200` you should go to `a//2` instead. Finally, your division will never give `y=0` I think you meant to use the `%` operator instead.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
a = int(input("give me a number:"))

for i in range(1, a//2+1):
    if not a%i:
        print(i)
```

Output (with `a=10`):

```
1
2
5
```

Comment: Ok many thanks for these many many remarks. But I have some questions you say "Finally, your division will never give y=0 I think you meant to use the % operator instead." ===> Why would I never get 0 as a division?

Comment: you only get 0 doing division if you divide by infinity

Comment: It seems I cannot accept two answer I am sorry, I wish I could accept yours as well.

Comment: well you should accept the answer which was the most helpful in finding the solution

Comment: OK on that point, maybe I am profoundly stupid: "Secondly, you're dividing by x which is a range object, you should instead divide by elem." ...but I was hoping that the result would be "take all elements of X". No?

Comment: nope, if you want to do something like that, then you should look at numpy arrays [basic array operations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#basic-array-operations) otherwise you have to do it element wise like I've shown

Comment: Ok many thanks, I will have a look.